# Adding Disqus Commenting Box on a Full Width Post and Pages in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I have installed Disqus commenting plugin on my website - however, it shows up on all posts. Though it does not show up on ''Full Width Posts'' and Pages. For example, http://www.yosaki.com/how-to-create-a-blog-and-make-money/   (that is a full width post not a page - but still Disqus can't show up)

Please help me get a solution because I would like to interact with my audience since it is an instructional post which requires instant support to my readers.